# I am getting an execption as object reference not set to an instance of an object. Code is as follows :

Tags: winforms

```
public void showdata(string pss, string cipherText)
    {
        SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(str);
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update Tbl_Users set Password = '" + pss + "'where Password ='" + cipherText + "'", conn1);
        SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        sda1.Fill(ds1, "Tbl_Users");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = ds1.Tables["Tbl_Users"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Can you debug the code and find out which line is throwing that error.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can make it a lot easier for others to answer your question, if you follow [these](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines. Please make sure to edit your post accordingly, as a lack of quality in a question might result in others not bothering to answer

Comment: on which line ur getting this error

Comment: dataGridView1.DataMember = ds1.Tables["Tbl_Users"].ToString();              In this line i am getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ur Updated Ans

```
  public void showdata(string pss, string cipherText)
        {
            SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(str);


> SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("**update Tbl_Users set Password = '" +
> pss + "'where Password ='" + cipherText + "'"**, conn1);
```

**It should be select statment not  Update Or Inser Statment**

```
 SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        Datatable ds1 = new Datatable ();
        sda1.Fill(ds1);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1;
    }
```

Comment: Sir , This code after debugging is not displaying my table/data in datagrid.  I want to display my  table to datagrid after updating.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir for your help. I have created another method for select query. Now its Working fine.

Comment: pl makr it as ans it will be appreciated